# Scala-xml (Scala 2.10.x) import error (Spark 1.6.0)

Tags: xml, scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

Im having a little problem importing the scala.xml.NodeSeq module into my project.

Im using this module to parse number of XML´s. But I keep getting "unable to resolve symbol" each time I want to use a NodeSeq variable.

I started off using Scala 2.11.7 but then I realized that Spark 1.6.0 uses scala 2.10.5.

Does any one know why I am unable to use the import scala.xml.NodeSeq in scala 2.10.5?

Im noticing that this error is having a lot to due with the scala-compiler dependency that I am using...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

If I  swap the version to the 2.11.7  my problem goes away, but ofcourse I need them all of the dependencies to be in the same version of scala.

PS: The IDE I am using is Intellij

Cheers!!

Comment: I keep getting "unable to resolve symbol" each time I want to use a NodeSeq variable, or each time i want to access info in my xml...

Answer (score 1):

Scala's XML support was moved to a standalone library in 2.11. You'll need to add it as a dependency in Maven:

```
<groupId>org.scala-lang.modules</groupId>
<artifactId>scala-xml_2.11</artifactId>
<version>1.0.3</version>
```

or in SBT:

```
"org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. It looks like Scala 2.10 xml library doesnt recognize the line :

```
val xml_v = xml \ "YOUR_XML_HEADER" \ @"XML_VARIABLE_YOU_WANT_TO_PARSE"
```

Instead you need to use:

```
val xml_v = xml \ "YOUR_XML_HEADER" \ "@XML_VARIABLE_YOU_WANT_TO_PARSE"
```

With the arroba inside the double brackets.